# Консоль не выводит скопированный текст по команде print

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Программа должна скопировать часть текста с определенного слова до конечного. Проблема в том, что текст берется из файла, копируется в pyperclip, который потом никак не взаимодействует с командой print

Подскажите, как быть

````
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
            str = f.read()
            pyperclip.copy(str)

a = pyperclip.paste()
x = a
print(x[x.find('справка об') : x.find('.')])```
````

Comment: вы не пробовали заменить переменную `str`, например на `my_str` ?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Но я убирал эту строку. Ничего не менялось

Comment: В чем проблема? С моей стороны этот код работает. Единственный минус, что он не решает описаную вами задачу (зачем копируется весь текст то?), и выводит срез, включающий "справка об", что сбивает с толку (возможно, это и есть искомая ошибка? В конце print'а среза нету точки, что говорит о корректной работе. Возможно ли, что достаточно просто прибавить длинну "справка об" к начальному индексу среза?).

Comment: Попробуйте напечатать отдельно `print(x)`, `print(x.find('справка об'))`, `print(x.find('.'))` - что выведется?

Comment: У вас либо "Справка" с большой буквы в файле, либо завершающей точки нет, например

Answer (score 1):

Все работает

```
import pyperclip


my_str = '''
справка об
Программа должна скопировать часть текста с определенного слова до конечного. Проблема в том, 
что текст берется из файла, копируется в pyperclip, который потом никак не взаимодействует 
с командой print.
'''

print(my_str)
print()

pyperclip.copy(my_str)

a = pyperclip.paste()

print(a[a.find('справка об') : a.find('.')])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если из файла? текст то он может скопировать без проблем

Comment: `my_str = f.read()`

Comment: перед этим дописываю with open(filepath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f: my_str = f.read() и все равно то же самое

Answer (score 0):

str - встроенная функция питона, вы не можете в нее что-то записать

```
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        arg = f.read()
        pyperclip.copy(arg)
```

или попробуйте `return`

```
def filereader(file):
    a = ''
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
           a += line
        return a
```